# I am using Firebase Apple sign-in for for android

Tags: java, android, firebase

I am using Firebase Apple sign-in for for android i put the

> https://myapp.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/handler

in apple developer console the callback url is not working. The callback URL return **the requested action is invalid**

Comment: can anyone help me to solve this issue its very urgent for me.

Comment: The issue is still open https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/1943

Comment: I resolved the issue the vivo mobile browser is not able to return the callback result to app thats y the problem is occured. Its worked in Chrome Browser.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue after enabling restriction on the API key. But resolved after adding https://myapp.firebaseapp.com/* to HTTP referrers.

You can find all the API keys in https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials